# Crosscompiling zlib for arm64/aarch64

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, cross-compiling, zlib

I have to crosscompile **zlib** on my x86_64 Ubuntu system for Android arm64/aarch64 as I want to use it inside of an app. I got the zlib from the official website (version 1.2.13). Inside of the folder I execute

```
CHOST=arm64 ./configure
```

Which executes without errors and then I run `make` which results in an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: deflate.lo: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_length_code' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:278: libz.so.1.2.13] Error 1
```

Building it for x86_64 works completely fine. Am I missing any flags here? Not sure if the `recompile with -fPIC` is actually the solution or just missing something.

Comment: In configure.log, does it say "... using gcc"?

Comment: It says ```arm64-cc -c ztest13213.c``` and in the next line ```... using cc```

Comment: What does `cc -v` print?

Comment: Using built-in specs. //
COLLECT_GCC=cc //
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper //
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa //
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1 //
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu // so this is only x86_64?

Comment: How about `arm64-cc -v`?

Comment: ```command not found```, but running your suggestion ```CC=gcc CHOST=arm64 ./configure``` seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mark Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler)s suggestion I found the solution. Despite the system found gcc, it is necessary to explicitly set gcc as compiler.

The solution is:

```
CC=gcc CHOST=arm64 ./configure
```